# How can I manually install a package/reference in my .Net Core project with VS Code

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, visual-studio-code

I recently tried using VS Code instead of Visual Studio 2019 Community and just ran into my first problem. If you want to add a reference manually in VS 2019 you can simply right click on 'References' and click on 'Add Reference'. I am now using VS Code to work on my C# Project and my next Step requires the *System.Drawing.Common* DLL.

The problem is - There is no 'Reference' folder in VS Code, so I don't know what to do. I've installed the C# extension for VS Code but there is still no option to add install packages or import references manually.

Can anyone help me? I'm desperate.

Comment: you can edit `*.csproj` file, or use `dotnet add package <package_name>` for .net core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use .NET Core, the easiest way is to use the .NET Core CLI alongside VS Code.

You can use the command `dotnet add package System.Drawing.Common` in the folder which contains your project and its `.csproj` file.

---

You can also manually edit the `.csproj` file and add the following block :

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="4.7.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The package will be loaded when building or running your app from VS Code or the .NET Core CLI.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add standalone DLL, do it like this.
1- Modify the *.csproj-file and under `</PropertyGroup>` tag, add your reference like this.

```
    <ItemGroup>
     <Reference Include="DllrefrenceFile">
       <HintPath>..\Dlls\DllrefrenceFile.dll</HintPath>
     </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
```

2- Move the dll to the root of your project.
3- using console/terminal go to the root directory of your project and execute `dotnet restore` to import all the references.
4- execute `dotnet run`

---

If you need to add package to your project, you can install the NuGet Package Manager extension for vscode and after that install your packages to your project like this.

1. Press Ctrl+Shift+P
2. Then select "Nuget Package Manager:Add Package"
3. Enter package name Ex: EntityFramework
4. select package name and version

Comment: This would normally be correct for a standalone DLL, but not for a framework reference

Comment: If you need to add package to your project, you can install the NuGet Package Manager extension for vscode. Than press Ctrl+Shift+P and select "Nuget Package Manager:Add Package" and Enter package name Ex: EntityFramework